# Why did my hard drive shrink?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I rebooted a computer yesterday and had a strange thing happen: When I had booted it back up, one of the hard drives was about a megabyte smaller. I have four 3 TB hard drives in this computer, in pairs of RAID1 mdraid arrays, making up an LVM VG. The drives were originally equally large, at 5860533168 * 512 byte sectors, and this one drive is now only 5860531055 sectors. Which is particularly strange as this drive is a 4k-sector drive (obviously, as it's 3 TB). So I would expect the size in 512-byte sectors to at least be divisible by 8, which it isn't.

As the drives are GPT-partitioned, this meant that the kernel (reasonably) rejected its partition table and detected no partitions on it, which meant that the RAID array it was part of was left degraded. I had a spare that I could insert into the array, though, so no harm was done per se. (And yes, I do realize I should have reserved space at the end of the drives so as to not rely on their exact sizes, but I didn't think of that when I created the arrays. I do plan on fixing it.)

My question is simply: What happened to this drive? Is it a known failure mode for hard drives to suddenly shrink? (I haven't heard about it, at least.) SMART doesn't report anything wrong about the drive at all -- no pending or reallocated sectors or anything else that I can see that sticks out.

Comment: What is the output of this (Linux) command: `sudo hdparm -N /dev/sdX`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Huh, you're right; HPA has become enabled, and that is indeed the entirety of the problem. Why is that, though? What would cause it to enable spontaneously?